# Microsoft Graph: Unable to Select ExtensionAttributes when using Delta Query?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been using the Microsoft Graph to perform [Delta Queries on Users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users). My requirement is to return the values of `ExtensionAttributes` (custom properties synced to Azure AD from AD on-prem).

The following request works:

`/v1.0/users?$select=extension_8928938292839829832_value`

And returns the extension attributes as desired:

```
 "value": [
        {
            "extension_8928938292839829832_value": "String1",
        }
```

However when trying to use the Delta Query and including extension attributes:

`/v1.0/users/delta?$select=extension_8928938292839829832_value`

The value returned is just the basic user properties, NOT the requested extension value:

```
 "value": [
        {
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "assignedLicenses": [],
            etc, etc, etc
        },
```

I'm not sure if the extension values are exposed in the v1.0 Delta Query.

Anyone have thoughts on how to approach this issue? Grabbing these extension attributes and using the delta query to track changes is vital to my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't supported at the moment. This is listed in the [Known Issues](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#delta-query):

> #### Delta query
>
> - OData context is sometimes returned incorrectly when tracking changes to relationships.
> - *Schema extensions (legacy) are not returned with $select statement, but are returned without $select.*
> - *Clients cannot track changes to open extensions or registered schema extensions.*